# SDO vs DB Adapter oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, sdo

I publish this post in order to reveal the underlying idea of the real use of this tecnology.
I know this isn't a common question, but it doesn't mean that it isn't important.

If you were trying to work with lots of tables of a Database, and you were using lots of BPEL Services, would you choose SDO (Service Data Objects) instead of DBAdapters (DataBase Adapters)??

I have been working for few weeks with SDOs and I find these really useful, but I'm not sure if the use of SDOs is better than DB Adapters or not...

What do you think about this??  SDOs or DBAdapters??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically SDO is Oracle SOA's attempt at an ORM and therefore you can simple look for information on ORM compared to JDBC. The DBAdaper is slight different from plain JDBC in it has extra features around polling and stored procedure integration.

DBAdapter for -> Simple SQL, Stored procedures, basic read write, delete and update and polling
SDO -> Highly reuseable code and everything that doesn't suit DBAdapter.

Here is a thread to look at http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/14117-jdbc-or-orm-framework-what-are-the-pros-and-cons